# java.lang.IllegalStateException?

Tags: android, bitmap, illegalstateexception

I am getting daily basis crash reports at google play console in one of my application.

The crash log is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkRecycled (Bitmap.java:394)
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.writeToParcel (Bitmap.java:1599)
  at miui.security.ISecurityManager$Stub$Proxy.saveIcon (ISecurityManager.java:1505)
  at miui.security.SecurityManager.saveIcon (SecurityManager.java:275)
  at com.miui.internal.os.Native.invoke (Native.java)
  at miui.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:120)
  at miui.content.res.ThemeRuntimeManager.saveIconInner (ThemeRuntimeManager.java:185)
  at miui.content.res.ThemeRuntimeManager.-wrap1 (SourceFile)
  at miui.content.res.ThemeRuntimeManager$ThemeServiceThread.run (ThemeRuntimeManager.java:159)
```

I do not use any `recycle bitmap` in my application. I do not parcel any `bitmap` in `intent`. So, not able to find the location of the crash. If any body knows how to get the error location/line please help.

I am loading installed application icon using Picasso like this:

```
  Picasso
                        .with(activity.getApplicationContext())
                        .load(IconRequestHandler.getUri(appsListItems.get(position).getPackageName()))
                        .fit()
                        .error(R.drawable.ic_default)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default)
                        .into(holder.icon);
```

Comment: is that full stacktrace?

Comment: miui rom, are you using Glide, Picasso or some image loading library?

Comment: @rupinderjeet I am using Picasso library to load mobile installed applications icon.

Comment: @Hemant Parmar yes this is full stack trace

Comment: Please add the code you use to load the image with Picasso. Are you using something custom for Picasso?

Comment: @rupinderjeet I am simply passing the package name to IconRequestHandler to get uri to load installed apps icons.

Comment: I have exactly this issue , and I can't find the error

Comment: Getting the same exception, my app also loads app icons using Picasso. If this is a new Xiaomi security concept, I'm not sure how custom launchers work

Comment: I have same problem on xiaomi roms with Android 8.1. Any update?

Answer (score 0):

After the investigation, I found that the problem is to call the `BitmapDrawable.getBitmap` method. The easiest solution to convert Drawable to Bitmap for me is:

```
Drawable d = packageManager.getApplicationIcon("com.example.appPackage");
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
d.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
d.draw(canvas);
```

Works fine on Xiaomi devices.